# show hide div after click transition-group in vue 3

Tags: vuejs3

I need that after clicking old element hide with animation and a new one also show with animation

Template:

```
<div id="app">
 
  
      <transition-group name="list">
        <div style="cursor:pointer" v-for="(item,key,i) in array" :key="i" class="list-item" >
          <div @click="select(key)">{{key}}</div>
        </div>
      </transition-group>
   
  <div>
   {{element}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Script:

```
export default {
  name: 'App',
 data() {
    return {
    element:"hello",
    array: ["hello","hello1","hello2"],
    }
  
  },
   methods:{
     select(key){
       this.element = this.array[key]
     }
   },
  components: {
    HelloWorld
  }
}
```

Style:

```
.list-item {
  transition: all 1s;
}
.list-leave-active {
  display: none;
}
.list-enter {
  opacity: 0;
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-tr9ucq?file=src/App.vue

Answer (score 0):

See [this snippet](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-pguset?file=src/App.vue) inspired by Vue official doc https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html

You were missing the logic to update your list (add/remove items) to trigger vue transition.

```html
 <transition-group name="list" tag="div" class="list">
        <span
          v-for="(item, index) in array"
          v-bind:key="item"
          @click="remove(index)"
          class="list-item"
        >
          {{ item }}
        </span>
      </transition-group>
```

Pass the index through click event then do your logic to update your array

```js
methods: {
    remove(index) {
      this.removed.push(this.array[index]);
      this.array.splice(index, 1);
    },
  },
```

Comment: What is it removed method?( this.removed)